# Positioning of Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Is it possible to set the position of a fab from the code?

For example I have these 2 fabs:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
FloatingActionButton editFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.editFab);
```

"fab" is the default fab, that comes as example after I  create a blank activity and editFab is my fab

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/editFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
```

[image]

Is it possible to position "editFab" above the "fab" button from the code? Or I have to do it in the xml layout?

Comment: Why you want to put it above fab?? why don't you just use `fab`??

Comment: @jankigadhiya I would like to have 2 fabs

Comment: add fab in relative layout and position it where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html
FloatingActionButton does not have any public setter methods to set its position.
So I guess you have to position it on your layout.
Just show/hide it in your code if you want to "add" it programmatically.